# two dataframes, if column1 value is == column of other dataframe then print column 2

Tags: python, pandas

if dataframe 1 column == dataframe 2 column , then print the colum2 in df2.

**dataframe1**

```
ColumnA 
john
mike
rose
lilly
duke
harry
```

**dataframe 2**

```
column A      ColumnB
john              aus
jonson            swiss
jerry             ireland
tom               europe
nik               england
jullie            london
mike              newjersy
suppy             china
rose              japan
peter             newyork
lilly             london
duke               us
harry              uk
```

output should be

if column A in Dataframe1 == column A in datframe 2 then print columnB in dataframe1 
required output should be
**dataframe1**

```
ColumnA   columnB
john        aus
mike        newjersy
rose        japan
lilly       london
duke         us
harry        uk
```

Can anyone help me out of this thanks inadvance

Comment: Use `df = df2[df2['ColumnA'].isin(df1['ColumnA'])]`

Comment: thank you jezrael but i want print columnB also in dataframe 1 which matches columnA

Comment: I think solution above working nice, there is some problem?